# Access SOAP API through a REST API in Java

Tags: java, rest, soap, jax-rs, soap-client

I have an application that exposes a SOAP API that some client I would like to access externally from another application. I am able to send a SOAP request to that API successfully.
However, the data returned by the API requires some modifications before sending the response back to the requesting Client. So I decided that I develop another API this time a rest API (because it appears rest is more flexible) to work as below:

1. Requests are sent to the Rest API
2. Rest API converts request to a a SOAP request and sends to the SOAP API
3. SOAP API sends back SOAP response to Rest API
4. Rest API formats SOAP response as required and sends response to client

I'm able to send a request to the rest API.

I'm also able to send a request from a SOAP client to the SOAP API.

My issue is how to forward the request through the REST API to the SOAP API and get a response back through the same. To me this looks like the REST API will act as a SOAP client in a way. Tried googling but not really getting much.

Please share any steps, links or even examples that I can use.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, previously I have done this by making the Rest Appi a SOAP client also, It then gets the data from SOAP service, converts to whatever you need, and sends it as REST reponse. Oout of the box, this is synchronous, so you might get delays while one service calls the other.

Comment: hi @jr593 how did u make the Rest API a soap client?

Comment: in the same way that you write code in your REST client, you write code in your SOAP client (REST endpoint). e.g. if your REST API is written in ruby you could use savon as the soap client https://github.com/savonrb/savon